# Adding a Row in a dataset.csv file through using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have tried .append method. the code is right but its not doing anything.
my .csv is too large to open i cant physically add there so please if anyone can fix my problem pls answer:

`Code:`

```
import pandas as pd

ARP_MitM_dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/ARP MitM_dataset-002.csv');
label = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/ARP MitM_labels.csv');


t = iter(range(1, 401))
ARP_MitM_dataset.columns = ['Column'+str(i).format(next(t)) if 1 <= i <= 499 else x for i, x in enumerate(ARP_MitM_dataset.columns, 1)]

dataArr = ARP_MitM_dataset

labelArr = label

dataArr.append({' ':2504267}, ignore_index = True)  <------ Check

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataArr,labelArr, test_size = 0.40, random_state = 42)  <--- Error

print(X_train.shape,y_train.shape)

print(X_test.shape,y_test.shape)
```

`Error Showing:`

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
> samples: [2504266, 2504267]

Comment: add = {'Column1': ['380.76885']}
data2 = pd.DataFrame(add)

dataArr = ARP_MitM_dataset
labelArr = label

dataArr.append(data2, ignore_index = True, sort = False)  


dataArr

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER grow a DataFrame. Always append your data to a list and convert it to a DataFrame once at the end because:-

1.) It is always cheaper/faster to append to a list and create a DataFrame in one go.

2.) Lists take up less memory and are a much lighter data structure to work with, append, and remove.

3.) `dtypes` are automatically inferred for your data. On the flip side, creating an empty frame of NaNs will automatically make them object, which is bad.

4.) An index is automatically created for you, instead of you having to take care to assign the correct index to the row you are appending.

You could try something like this:-

```
data = []
for a, b, c in some_function_that_yields_data():
    data.append([a, b, c])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Comment: There is 2504266 rows × 115 columns in my dataset

Comment: I just want to add a another row to have total of 2504267 rows

Comment: Kindly check my edited answer

Comment: I did this in this manner still its not working .

Comment: @Gee if your data is not sensitive, can you provide a link to your data sets?

Comment: @Talha First add the data you want to an empty list. Convert it into a dataframe and then append that dataframe to your original one

Comment: @Talha It would be much better if you could provide a link to your dataset and the new data that you want to add